# What's the best way to distinguish if a ClearCase element is part of UCM environment?

Tags: clearcase

I do some scripting and I have to support both Base and UCM.

I get an element name and I have to figure out if that's part of UCM environment or not.
What's the most efficient way to do so?
e.g.
check the view config-spec for UCM statement?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `cleartool catcs`, anywhere within your view.

The config spec of an UCM vie is quite distinct of a baseline ClearCase one:

It will begin with

```
ucm
identity UCM.Stream ...
```

So unless you have special base ClearCase selection rules in the last part of the config spec:

```
#UCMCustomElemBegin - DO NOT REMOVE - ADD CUSTOM ELEMENT RULES AFTER THIS LINE

[... my base ClearCase selection rules ...]

#UCMCustomElemEnd - DO NOT REMOVE - END CUSTOM ELEMENT RULES
```

You can consider than your element, selected by an UCM view, is part of an UCM environment.